# Update input value from state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im encountering an issue where inputs, and in this case select input is not updating when state is updated. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectType:'1'
    }
   }

    onChangeEndpointType(event) {
        this.setState=({
          selectType:event.target.value, 
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select name="selecttype" value={this.state.selectType} onChange={() => this.onChangeEndpointType(event)}>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        )}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the setState has a typo, try this:

```
 onChangeEndpointType(event) {
     // setState 
     this.setState({
       selectType:event.target.value, 
     })
    }
```

Comment: yep dumb move on my part. Sometimes all you need is an extra pair of eyes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind this of function with this of constructor:
vote if it works

```
class Page extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectType:'1'
    }
    this.onChangeEndpointType = this.onChangeEndpointType.bind(this);
}

    onChangeEndpointType(event) {
        this.setState=({
        selectType:event.target.value, 
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select name="selecttype" value={this.state.selectType} onChange={() => this.onChangeEndpointType(event)}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couble of bugs in your code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectType:'1'
    }
  }

  onChangeEndpointType(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectType:event.target.value, 
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <select name="selecttype" value={this.state.selectType} onChange={(event) => this.onChangeEndpointType(event)}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

One is setState syntax error

```
this.setState({
  selectType:event.target.value, 
})
```

Another one is you have pass event in the onChange callback

```
onChange={(event) => this.onChangeEndpointType(event)}
```